# Simplifying PostgreSQL Full Text Search tsvector and tsquery with aliases

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I am trying to simplify this query as it is going to be dynmaically generated by PHP and I would like to reduce the processing overhead (the real query will be much longer but the structure will be the same!).

```
SELECT title, type_name, ts_rank_cd(ARRAY[0.1,0.2,0.4,1.0],
setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(title,'')), 'A')
||
setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(type_name,'')), 'B')
,
to_tsquery('search & query'))
FROM TestView WHERE
setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(title,'')), 'D')
||
setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(type_name,'')), 'B')
@@
to_tsquery('search & query');
```

I am looking to try to reduce the need to specify the tsquery and tsvector twice by defining something like an alias so that it does not have to be specified twice. Something like this (which fails, I am not sure if it is even close to correct!)

```
SELECT title, type_name, ts_rank_cd(ARRAY[0.1,0.2,0.4,1.0],
searchvector
,
searchquery
FROM TestView WHERE
setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(title,'')), 'D')
||
setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(type_name,'')), 'B') AS searchvector
@@
to_tsquery('search & query') AS searchquery;
```

Is this possible or am I just stuck with generating it all twice.

For context 'TestView' is a view generated from a number of tables.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT title, 
       type_name,
       ts_rank_cd(ARRAY[0.1,0.2,0.4,1.0],weight,query)
FROM (
    SELECT title, 
           type_name, 
           setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(title,'')), 'A')
              ||setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(type_name,'')), 'B') as weight,
           to_tsquery('search & query') as query
    FROM TestView 
) t
WHERE weight @@ query
```

Comment: Thanks but that still fails... ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 7: ...tweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(type_name,'')), 'B') as weight,

Comment: I think I misunderstood the call to ts_rank_cd(). Please try the new query. But anyhow, that should give you an idea how to deal with this.

Comment: Still fails unfortunately... with your new edit the error is ERROR:  function ts_rank_cd(numeric[]) does not exist which I think is due to an errant bracket on line 5, removing that throws the same error as above. ts_rank_cd params are rank array, tsvector, tsquery. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.